# Есть ли у boost::lockfree::queue определяемый передел расширения, или очередь будет расширяться, пока не закончится память?

Tags: c++, boost, очередь, lock-free

У lockfree::queue присутствует конструктор, принимающий численное значение, документация крайне скудная, я не могу понять, что он означает. Изначально я думал, что это максимально возможное количество элементов в очереди, но код ниже показал, что это не так, т.к достигнув переданного в конструктор значения очередь продолжила расширяться. Вопрос в том, что означает этот конструктор и может ли эта очередь расширяться бесконечно?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::lockfree::queue<int> queue(1);
    bool test1 = queue.push(1);
    bool test2 = queue.push(2);
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    queue.pop(a);
    queue.pop(b);
    std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Там же написано `Construct queue, allocate n nodes for the freelist.` Чтобы указать максимальный размер следует использовать политику `boost::lockfree::capacity`

Comment: @user7860670, что в данном контексте означает freelist?

Comment: перечень свободных блоков

Comment: @user7860670, а если не указывать boost::lockfree::capacity, максимальный размер будет ограничен?

Comment: Да, получится очередь с фиксированной емкостью